# Converting text into array

Tags: python, file-io, split

I am trying to split a text from textfile into a sort of array by using .split(',')
The text file consists of some lines with 10 values separated by a comma:

> 11BIT,0,20110112,090010,8.01,8.01,8.01,8.01,10,0
>   11BIT,0,20110112,094206,8.01,8.01,8.00,8.00,474,0
>   11BIT,0,20110112,113648,8.04,8.04,8.04,8.04,148,0

```
with open("txtfile", 'r') as elevenbit:
    for line in elevenbit:
        line=elevenbit.readline()
        for x in line:
            print(x, end='')
```

Could you please tell how to split these lines within for loop and assign particular values to variables, like this:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = lines.split(',')
```

Comment: Using both `for line in file` and `file.readline()` is probably not what you're hoping to do. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the list returned by `split` to a tuple

```
with open("txtfile", 'r') as elevenbit:
    for line in elevenbit:
        line=elevenbit.readline()
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = tuple(line.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objects_in_lines = list()
with open("txtfile", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        objects_in_lines.append(line.split(','))
```

The result will be a large list, within it is a small list for every line. Each small list will have all the objects in the line.